# (not so) Spectacular $\ 7^3$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Indeed,

**Conjecture**   Let $\ p\ $ be a prime, $\ n>1\, $ -- a natural number, and let the largest prime divisor $\ q\ $ of $\ s(p^n) :=\sum_{k=0}^n\,p^k\ $ satisfy $ q<p.\ $ Then $\ p^n\ =\ 7^3.$

The unique(?) exception would be

$$ s(7^3)\ =\ 400\ = 2^4\cdot5^2 $$

> 

**EDIT** A micro-observation: when primes
$\ p\ q\ r\ $ satisfy $\ q|s(p^{r-1})\ $ then
$\ p>r\ $ and $\ q\ge r$.

More generally, $\ p>\rho $ and $\ q\ge \rho\ $ when $\ \rho\ $ is the smallest prime divisor of $\ r\,\ $ where this time $\ r\ $ is **not** assumed to be a prime.

Comment: A numerical search for $2\leq p\leq 1000$ and $2\leq n\leq 20$ turned up 79 counterexamples.

Comment: Thank you. I am spectacularly wrong.

Comment: Would someone kindly add these counterexamples to OEIS? I feel that these examples are essential to the theory of perfect and baroque (multi-perfect) numbers.

Comment: The counterexample values $p^n$ up to one million are $343,
 4489,
 6241,
 18769,
 22201,
 26569,
 32761,
 36481,
 44521,
 52441,
 68921,
 69169,
 72361,
 76729,
 79507,
 97969,
 103823,
 139129,
 185761,
 192721,
 249001,
 271441,
 326041,
 389017,
 398161,
 426409,
 571787,
 619369,
 654481,
 657721,
 674041,
 677329,
 844561,
 896809,
 942841,
 982081,
 994009$. I'll leave it to someone else to post to OEIS if they are inclined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's also

$$s(67^2) = 1 + 67 + 67^2 = 4557 = 3 \cdot 7^2 \cdot 31 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

In this case, $q = 31 \lt 67$ meets your criteria. I haven't checked further, but I'm fairly certain there are additional exceptions.

Comment: Thank you. This is a surprise(!) due to the even exponent, $\ 67^2.$

Comment: @WlodAA For small $n$, there are lots and lots of examples. -- But there is also e.g. $s(493397^6) = 29^2 \cdot 127 \cdot 1163 \cdot 2129 \cdot 4229 \cdot 26041 \cdot 50177 \cdot 71359 \cdot 138349$.

Comment: @StefanKohl, impressive!